# as3 for loop not loading code efficiently - Creating random mp3 playlist

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, for-loop, loading

I have this function that I putting in an app to run on Droid and IOS devices.

**Purpose: It goes thru 10 folders each containing mp3s. It gets the contents and selects on randomly from the folder and puts that random mp3 into another array with the other randomly selected mp3s. This final array is the random playlist.**

Most of the time it works but sometimes the first Var is left blank. I am wondering if the second array is trying to get the contents of the first array and the cpu is running slow so maybe it does not work sometimes.

Is there a way to get this code follows a particular order to ensure proper functioning?

```
function loadRandomMeditations(Language:String,CurrentMystery:String,CurrentDecade:String)
    {

    RandomSounds = [];
    TempArray = [];

    sounds = [];
    for(var a:int = 1; 11>a;a++)
        {
            var folder:String = "Languages/" + Language + "/Meditations/" + CurrentMystery + "/"+CurrentDecade+"/"+a+"/";
            var desktop:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(folder);
            var medSound:Array = desktop.getDirectoryListing();

            /// Looping thru to get all sounds in this directory
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < medSound.length; i++)
                {
                            // puts all sounds of folder into a temporary array
                TempArray.push(medSound[i].url);
                }

                    /// This counts the array and chooses a random number.
            var num = 1 + Math.round(Math.random()*(medSound.length-1));

                    //Adds Zero to make counting even
            TempArray.unshift("Zero");

            /// Puts the randomly selected array item into another array.
            RandomSounds.push(TempArray[num]);

            sounds[a] = new Sound(new URLRequest(TempArray[num]));
            TempArray = [];
        }
    trace(RandomSounds);

}
```

**OUTPUT: Sometimes the 1st mp3 is not loaded into the final playlist array.**

Answer (score 0):

You over complicated your function

```
function loadRandomMeditations(Language:String,CurrentMystery:String,CurrentDecade:String)
  {
  var medSound:Array = []
  var RandomSounds:Array = [];
  var sounds:Array = [];
  var folder:String = "Languages/" + Language + "/Meditations/" + CurrentMystery + "/"+CurrentDecade+"/";
  var desktop:File;
  var i:int;
  var num:int;
  // stay with the standard and use Lower Case I in a for loop
  for(i = 1; 11>i;i++)
    {
    desktop = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(folder+i+"/");
    medSound= desktop.getDirectoryListing();

    // This counts the array and chooses a random number.
    // not sure why you have a 1 + on this but it needs to go
    num = Math.round(Math.random()*(medSound.length-1));

    // why create a second "temp" array when you can just pick one off the medSound array
    // Puts the randomly selected array item into another array.
    RandomSounds.push(medSound[num].url);

    sounds[a] = new Sound(new URLRequest(medSound[num].url));
  }
  trace(RandomSounds);
}
```

Comment: Would i use sounds[i] and not sounds[a]? This is not working even when I put i in place of a.

Comment: For some reason the TempArray.unshift("Zero"); Was necessary. I think it's because I don't have a folder called 0 but only 1 thru 10. If I don't add a zero somewhere it gets funky.

Comment: Yeah I don't know what the issue is but for some reason its not working. I think it has something to do with the zero I added on there. It needed it later because a script later calls the array from one to 10 and not zero to nine.